# Can't render a nested object from an array with Apollo and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sdxs.png)

Trying to get the nested data products.name to render on page. i tried doing this but it doesnt render anything, i want to get the products name and id ... but it is in nested array.I'm sure this is some syntax problem, thanks in advance

```
{data && data.categories.products?.map((product) => {
  return <div>
    <h1>Name : {product.products.name}</h1>
    <h3>ID :{product.products.id} </h3>  
    </div>
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render products for each category seperately

```
{data?.categories?.map((cat, catIdx) => {
  return (
     <div key={catIdx}>
        <span>Category Name<span>
        {
           cat.products?.map((product) => {


            // if gallery is array of object, then use the property
            // const imageSrc = product.gallery[0]?.src
            // if gallery is array of string
            const imageSrc = product.gallery[0]

              return (
                <div key={product.id}>
                  <h1>Name : {product.name}</h1>
                  <h3>ID :{product.id} </h3>  
                  <img src={imageSrc} alt={`product image for ${product.name}`} />
                </div>
              )
           })
        }
     </div>
  )
})}
```

If you want to show products of a specific category

```
const categoryIndex = 0;
{data?.categories[categoryIndex]?.map((cat, catIdx) => {
  return (
     <div key={catIdx}>
        <span>Category Name<span>
        {
           cat.products?.map((product) => {
              return (
                <div key={product.id}>
                  <h1>Name : {product.name}</h1>
                  <h3>ID :{product.id} </h3>  
                </div>
              )
           })
        }
     </div>
  )
})}
```

If you want to all products

```
// use useMemo if performance is an issue
const allProducts = data?.categories?.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return [ ...acc, ...(curr.products ?? []) ]
}, [])

 {
     allProducts?.map((product) => {

            / if gallery is array of object, then use the property
            // const imageSrc = product.gallery[0]?.src
            // if gallery is array of string
            const imageSrc = product.gallery[0]
         return (
            <div key={product.id}>
               <h1>Name : {product.name}</h1>
               <h3>ID :{product.id} </h3>  
               <img src={imageSrc} alt={`product image for ${product.name}`} />
             </div>
          )
       })
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks bro, and 1 more thing if i want to render specific array like products on 0 index then what will be the answer to it

Comment: @monisiqbal Welcome, I edited the answer, hope it helps

Comment: i tried this but it gives me blank page , there is a gallery array but i only want to show the 0 index img on the product list , like ps5 has 5 pics but i want to show only pic number 1 that is on 0 index of an array

Comment: @monisiqbal I edited the answer to show the first image, but I dont know what is inside the gallery array, so modify it according to what is inside the array

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `.products` in your variables (inside the html).

```
{data && data.categories.products?.map((product) => {
  return <div>
    <h1>Name : {product.name}</h1>
    <h3>ID :{product.id} </h3>  
    </div>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that each `product` has a property with `products` array, You need to loop again through the `products` array, so you will have two nested `map`.

```
{data && data.catergories.products?.map((product) => {
                return <div>
                    { product.products && product.products.map(subProducts => (<h1>Name : {subProducts.name}</h1>
                    <h3>ID :{subProducts .id} </h3>  ))
                </div>
            })}
```